# How to make text appear when hover over a href

Tags: html, css, text, href

How would I make text appear under a link?

```
<div class="login">
    <a href="">Login
    <p>Access your profile here</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Where the login triggers the p to show?

Do I need to use the p or something else?

Comment: The `<p>` is being *part of* the link. Anyway, this should work: `.login a:hover p { display:block }`

Comment: Use the Title attirbute inside the a tag.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following style makes the `p` visible on hover:

```css
.login a p {display:none;}
.login a:hover p {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="login">
    <a href="">Login
        <p>Access your profile here</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Or if you want the whole link including `p` inside stay visible together on hover use the following:

```css
.login a p {display:none;}
.login a:hover p {display:block;}
.login a:hover {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="login">
    <a href="">Login
        <p>Access your profile here</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: nice one, I just combined this with a bootstrap label inside a span, this way every time you hover a label, a box will appear underneath it! Thx for this!

Answer (score 59):

that's simple just add title attribute in  tag

```
<a href="http://www.studyofcs.com" title="Tricks Site">Studyofcs</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple Html Tooltip

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" title="Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers">stackoverflow</a>
```

Tooltip Using Bootstrap :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <p>The data-placement attribute specifies the tooltip position.</p>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Bottom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Left</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can achieve hover tooltip By Bootstrap+JQuery also :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using bootstrap you can use the following:

`<a class="login" href="" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Access your profile here">Login</a>`

Answer (score -1):

You just can use old title argument, works well, the shortest solution

Google

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).