# Text/Link appear on hover

Tags: css, hover

I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149360/text-on-image-mouseover) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400034/how-to-make-text-appear-when-hover-over-a-href) with no luck. My css file as it is:

```
.JFK {
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: -45px;
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.JFK a p{
    position: relative;
    top: -130px;
    display: none;
}
.JFK a:hover p{
    display: block;
}

.JFK:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}
```

My html:

```
<div class = "JFK">
        <p>JFK</p>
        <a href = "#"><p>to</p></a>
        <a href = "#"><p>from</p></a>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to have links appear at the bottom of the image upon hover. The solutions in previous posts have not worked. With my current setup, I cannot see "TO" or "FROM" at all when I load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover should be on the `.JFK` not the `.JFK a` When you hover over the .JFK it should make the `.JFK a p` visible.

```
.JFK:hover a p {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle with the change: https://jsfiddle.net/efv8ch70/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```css
.JFK {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
}
.JFK,
.JFK > p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.JFK > p {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.link-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.JFK:hover .link-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="JFK">
  <p>JFK</p>
  <div class="link-wrapper">
    <a href="#"><span>to</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>from</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are lots of ways to solve this problem.  This solution is just an example. The actual paragraph has the same hight as the .JFK so it pushes the .link-wrapper down to exactly the spot you want in the normal flow.  Hope this helps or gives you some ideas.